# Kafka Producer 0.8.2.1 warning

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I was able to setup a working java Kafka 0.8.2.1 producer. I need this producer to be async so that it doesn't block the thread. In the console output, I get this warning from the logger:

```
2016-06-10 10:55:27 WARN  ProducerConfig:121 % The configuration request.timeout.ms = null was supplied but isn't a known config.
2016-06-10 10:55:27 WARN  ProducerConfig:121 % The configuration producer.type = null was supplied but isn't a known config.
2016-06-10 10:55:27 WARN  ProducerConfig:121 % The configuration request.required.acks = null was supplied but isn't a known config.
```

Can anyone please tell me why I'm getting these warning and how to fix them? 
My producer config is:

```
bootstrap.servers=hostname:9092
client.id=java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
compression.type = none
producer.type=async
block.on.buffer.full=false
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
acks=all
request.required.acks=1
retries=2
request.timeout.ms=1200000
batch.size=16384
linger.ms=1
buffer.memory=33554432
```

Update1: Going through the Kafka Producer code, I do not see 'producer.type' property yet @  http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.8.2.1/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java?av=f

Update2:Does the Kafka Java Producer not have these properties?? Still stuck here, please can anyone help?

Comment: How does you $KAFKA_HOME/config/producer.properties look like - is that the one you posted ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same one.

Comment: Also, here http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs those configurations are not mentioned in valid java Producer config. In that case what properties should be specified to make the producer async?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#producerconfigs

Comment: But then why do I get the above warning for producer.type? :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your kafka cluster is up and working correctly and your producer code is giving the error. We will need to see the code of how your producer is being initialized. Typically you create a properties object with the necessary settings and pass that into a kafka.producer.ProducerConfig constructor. You can use the settings in producer.properties to start with.

e.g.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("request.timeout.ms", "1200000");
//add more settings to the props object
...
//finally pass in the config to the producer config.
ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
```

Comment: I am reading from a file that has this configuration and passing that to the Properties config. This(file i/o) is working fine. 
To test your theory, I even explicitly added  props.put("producer.type", "async"); but I still get the same warning.

Comment: Your warning is about request.timeout.ms , producer.type and request.required.acks, could you try adding those. Would be helpful to see the code that creates the Properties.

Comment: Yes, I added those explicitly:        props.put("producer.type", "async");
        props.put("request.required.acks", 1);
        props.put("request.timeout.ms", "1200000"); still I got the same warning. I want to make sure Producer is async. I even checked Producer config from documentation at  http://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#producerconfigs, which supports those three properties.

Comment: Also, it gets reads all the other configuration like hostname correctly, so I don't think it is a problem with reading the properties.

Comment: Actually, here http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs those configurations are not mentioned in valid java Producer config. In that case what properties should be specified to make the producer async?